# UIViewController width change when the keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, xib

I have an exampleUIViewController created with its `xib` file. The `mainView` contains some `textFields`. When a `textField` is clicked (to begin editing), I display the keyboard with animation:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

self.view.frame = self.initialFrame;

 [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
     {
         CGRect newFrame = [view frame];
         newFrame.origin.y -= PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
         [view setFrame:newFrame];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];
 return YES;
}
```

Then in the `textFieldShouldReturn`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

self.view.frame = self.initialFrame;
[textField resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
     {
         CGRect newFrame = [view frame];
         newFrame.origin.y += PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
         [view setFrame:newFrame];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];

return YES;
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` I set the `self.initialFrame` as:

`self.intialFrame = self.view.frame;`

The problem is that when the keyboard is displayed, the `mainView` width change and become bigger.

What is wrong with what I did?
Why have I this problem only with `xib` and not also with an `UIViewController` created in the `storyboard`?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the correct frame size at viewDidLoad(), try at viewDidAppear()

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the correct frame view with a xib or storyboard ViewController. Dont get the View with

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The best way to get the correct frame is

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.intialFrame = self.view.frame;
}
```